# Stop next mouseover event from firing until inner function has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing a simple image swapping feature with a fade in jquery.

```
$('#thumbs img').mouseover(function(){  
// code to swap images here
});
```

If I move the mouse really quickly the mouseover keeps firing and the code to swap the images cant keep up. How do I stop the mouseover event on $('#thumbs img') from firing until the inner code has executed ?

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#thumbs img').mouseover(function(){
  if(!moving){
    moving = true;
    // code to swap images here
    if(complete) // some test to see if image swap has finished
      moving = false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the evant handler while processing:

```
$('#thumbs img').mouseover(dostuff);

function dostuff()
{
    $(this).unbind('mouseover', dostuff);
    // code to swap images here
    $(this).mouseover(dostuff);
}
```

(Something like that - I cannot test it out atm ). What you are doing is removing the event handler while it is processing, and rebinding once it is complete.

Comment: recursively calling `doStuff` i think it will loop infinitely

Comment: I don't think it does if properly implemented, as I have done this previously. It only actually calls dostuff when the event is triggeres, not from within dostuff itself, so it is not recursive.